# "mix in a circular motion" vs. "mix with a circular motion"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, word-difference

Is there any difference betweeen "mix **in** a circular motion" and "mix **with** a circular motion"?

> Transfer 100 mL of solution 3 into the beaker and mix **with (in?)** a circular motion, avoiding foaming.

Would the versions with **in** and **with** be fully synonymous?

P.S.

As an afterthought: would "swirl to mix" be synonymous with "mix in a circular motion"?

Comment: Either is allowable, but I would probably use "with", mainly because *with* is always used when describing hand movements ("with a flick of the wrist", "with a wave of the hand”). However, since mechanical stirrers are often used in labs, "in" might be better.

Comment: **in** pertains to the movement of the thing being moved (the beaker and its contents); **with** refers to the motion of the thing moving the beaker (the arm).  state (in) versus instrumentality (with).

Comment: When you stir a can of paint *with* a circular motion, the paint in the can will swirl *in* a circular motion.

Comment: https://www.google.it/search?q=mix+in+a+circular+motion&oq=mix+in+a+cir&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8578j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=mix+ingredients++%22in+a+circular+motion%22&tbm=bks&start=0

Comment: Bond, James Bond. Shaken, not with a circular motion.

Comment: ^not stirred !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using either "**with** a circular motion" or "**in** a circular motion" would readily be understood

> [Stir - To mix using a spoon or wire whisk **with** a circular motion](https://quizlet.com/4576999/mixing-cooking-terms-flash-cards/)

the stirring implement moves **with** a circular motion, whereas

> [Beating - Mixing ingredients vigorously **in** a circular motion with a long spoon, wire whisk, or electric beater.](https://books.google.it/books?id=4tifS5S2UeoC&pg=PA496&dq=mix+ingredients++%22in+a+circular+motion%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0q_qy6oHRAhVp4oMKHRNBDCwQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=mix%20ingredients%20%20%22in%20a%20circular%20motion%22&f=false)

the ingredients move **in** a circular motion.

[image]

> The wisk is moved **with** a circular motion causing the eggs to move **in** a circular motion.

The main difference is how the rotation occurs around the "center" of *something*. If it is spinning on an axis, then it is "**in** a circular motion", if the axis is rotating or "[precessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession)" then it can be said to be "**with** a circular motion".  In the egg example, the whisk's central axis is moved around the egg's central axis.

In your example of a laboratory setting, when mixing with a beaker, usually a magnetic stirrer is placed inside and then is rotated forming a vortex which mixes the solution

[image]

> the stirring magnet moves "**in** a circular motion" since it is spinning about one of its axis

an alternative might be to use a [reciprocal shaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbxYDhZIW7U) in which case

> the entire beaker is moved "**with** a circular motion" around a central axis.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about cooking. What do you think about the OP's example?

Comment: Thank you for the add-on text about the "in-lab" contexts.

Comment: "beaker" implies a lab situation (unless it's a very mod bar), "foam" implies protein in solution is involved where foaming, which will denature proteins, is a concern, usually one doesn't "swirl" using a beaker in a lab the opening is too big, an erlenmeyer flask because of it's shape is more appropriate.